# case secanario probability

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a park there are 27 seats.Anyone can sit on any seat with the following restrictions-Whenever any new person comes and sit in any of the seat,any one of his/her neighbour(if there is any) should leave their seat.So they can be two cases:-1)New person can come and sit in the corner seat-in this case if there is any neighbour he/she should leave the seat.2)New person can come and sit in any seat other than corner-in this case any one of his/her neighbour (if there is any) should leave their seat.At most how many persons can be seated in the park?

Comment: So the seats are arranged in a row?

Comment: Nothing else is mentioned in the question.This the scenario.I am trying to figure out because the question is quite vague

Comment: Smartaleck answer: spread the seats around the park so that no seat is next to any other.  All 27 seats can be filled.  In all seriousness though, you haven't told us anything about how the seats are arranged.  Are they in a circle?  Are they in a line?

Comment: If you start playing with the problem, with any sequence of people sitting, what do you notice about the number of empty seats between people at any step in the process that people aren't actively being moved?  Is there always at least one empty seat between one person and the next?  Can you explain why?  Is there a pattern where there is exactly one seat between each person?  Can you reason that this must be the optimal solution?

Comment: There is nothing mentioned regarding this if they are in a line or circle.Is there any alternate approach to this case where you can relate to probability?

Comment: This problem has absolutely nothing to do with probability.  At best, it could be described as extremal combinatorics.  The answer to if they are in a line or in a circle will differ by one.

Comment: So what if they are in line or a circle how would be your approach towards the case?

Comment: I already explained it essentially in full in my second comment.  You recognize that there must always be at least one empty seat between filled seats, so the most number of seats used is at most half of the seats (rounded up).  Then you recognize that by alternating which seats are used you can achieve that.